# Clear "glass" bottle loses clearness in front of colored background

Tags: modeling, materials, light

So my Fiji water bottle is perfect clarity and clearness when it's by itself (as can be seen by the right most bottle). However when placed in front of a colored back ground and having a blue gradient back side label it basically turns almost black. I think it's the refraction / reflections causing it. Is there a way I can turn those down --or perhaps add a light behind the bottles that only affects the bottles and does not affect or blow out the background?

[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

---

Adding an emission light that only emits light in one direction and placed behind the bottles cleared up the issue of black bottles. However that presented the NEW issue of not allowing the backdrop to show through the bottles. As presented here: [Emission Light Problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44584/emission-light-needs-to-be-transparent)

[image]

Comment: Could you show your Light Path panel's settings?

Comment: That's a weird node setup, and yeah it won't allow the background to be seen, because no transmission is happening. Why don't you just use a standard Glass BSDF and make sure the bottles have some thickness by adding a Solidify Modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the glass was showing black (therefore no light passing through it) was for the reason there was actually a duplicate bottle within the bottle that I did not know about, plus the normals of that bottle were apparently backward. Once THAT bottle was deleted it appears everything works fine. Arrrgh. Very stupid error on my part. APOLOGY.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before. I am guessing the problem is with light paths in render settings.  If you don't have enough bounces, then having multiple transparent materials stacked behind one another will cause the darkening.

I'm pretty sure all I had to do was increase my minimum light bounces and it was fixed.  Good luck!

Edit: Minimum light bounces for transparency is the one you want to increase

Comment: I increased the minimum light paths, no change. Increased the maximum too. No change. Added a new screen shot to reflect those changes and show the light paths panel. And other suggestions?

Comment: Try increasing the minimum bounces for transparency or glossy

Comment: Thanks. Bumped them both to 100 no change. See new image.