# Emission Light Problem

Tags: modeling, rendering, node-editor, light

By adding an emission light behind the bottles, in front of the back drop I cleared up the issues with the black bottles as mentioned here: [Clear "glass" bottle loses clearness in front of colored background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44530/clear-glass-bottle-loses-clearness-in-front-of-colored-background/44537?noredirect=1#comment75037_44537)

However by doing so it created a new issue when that same corrective light now blocks the image behind it, thus not allowing that image to show through the transparent water bottles.  For clarification the emission light is moved over slightly and shown highlighted in red so you can see that it does reside between the bottles and the backdrop. I need that back drop to show THROUGH the bottles. Ideas? Suggestions? Solutions? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I THOUGHT The light was blocking the label behind it from showing through to the bottles in front of it. However it turns out there was actually a duplicate bottle within the bottle that I did not know about, plus the normals of that bottle were apparently backward. Once THAT was deleted it appears everything works fine. Arrrgh. Stupid error on my part. APOLOGY.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Select the emission Plane.  Set Cycles Ray Visibility Camera to False.

You may choose to locate the light or lights anywhere convenient.

Comment: Please enter your solution or update the original.  I will delete my proposed answer shortly.

Comment: I understand what you wrote.  I am just suggesting that you update your question. Create a new  answer and select it if possible. Otherwise put you answer in the original question itself.  So no one else tries to answer.  New title to question can be ... Emission Light Problem [Solved]